# PHP curl/REST sometimes VERY slow

Tags: php, curl

The worst examples are 23 minutes for a call that normally takes less than 4 seconds, and 7 minutes for a call that normally takes less than 1 second. I've never come across this issue before. It only happens maybe 5% or less of the time, and it is more likely to happen at the first call of the day.

An example of a call that took 8 minutes:

```
(
[url] => https://xxxxxxx/webservice/xxxx?offset=0&limit=1&xxxxx=xxxx
[content_type] => application/xml; charset=utf-8
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 501
[request_size] => 213
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 10
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 529.413661
[namelookup_time] => 0.441115
[connect_time] => 0.464504
[pretransfer_time] => 0.546094
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 14867
[speed_download] => 28
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.625664
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
[local_port] => 63322
```

)

As you can see "total_time" is very high.

A representative for the REST service said that none of their clients had reported anything similar in staging or production. (I'm using their staging server with localhost/XAMPP) They also can't see the long times on their side.

The function I'm using:

```
public function loadObjFromPath($path, $params = []) {
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    $credentials = "TEST:$this->key";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->baseUrl.$path.'?'.http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);        
    $xml_obj = simplexml_load_string($result);
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    error_log('Secs: '.($time_end - $time_start).' '.print_r($info, true));
    return $xml_obj;
}
```

If I can't figure out why this is happening I was thinking I would set a timeout of maybe 60 seconds or less and then get it to run the curl request again. At the moment it does eventually work properly (200 code) even if it does take 23 minutes. It has been happening for about 6 days - since I've started using it.

The first time I used it on another internet connection it took 31 seconds then it took less than 2 seconds. When it is taking a long time I run curl in other windows and they finish quickly simultaneously.

The following code seems to work:

```
public function loadObjFromPath($path, $params = [], $timeout = 60) {
....if ($timeout) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $secs = $time_end - $time_start;
    if ($timeout && empty($result) && $secs > $timeout) {
        error_log("Timeout: $timeout secs: $secs ".print_r($info,true));
        return $this->loadObjFromPath($path, $params, 0);
    }
```

CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT didn't seem to stop long calls from executing. When I use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and it takes longer to return than that, it still returns the 200 code, just with no result data.

Comment: Are you testing it on localhost or live server ? Because It also depends on your server speed.

Comment: [local_ip] => 192.168.11.206 - I'm running PHP on XAMPP on my Mac. I have a 50 Mbps connection. I am using curl to access their server on the public internet using their staging data.

Comment: Mmm: Is there a different computer you can use? Perhaps as well you can see what happens if you try a google api? https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/06/google-maps-geocoding-example-php.html Just thinking outside chance get a network checker - see if something is hogging that 50MB

Comment: Whenever I download backups from the cloud they are a consistent 5+ Mbytes/s. The XML data returned from curl is only a couple kb. I run the php code in different windows and during a long request others are still very quick. I've been working with curl for years and have never had this issue. Just with this particular API since I started using it. I have another internet provider I can use (though I prefer my normal one)